Visualizing the Effect of a Parameterized Gate on a Qubit Using the Bloch Sphere in Qiskit 1.0
I am seeking assistance with visualizing the effect of a parameterized gate on a qubit using the Bloch Sphere representation. I have a preliminary code snippet as follows:
from qiskit import *
from qiskit.circuit import Parameter

parameter = Parameter('x')

circuit = QuantumCircuit(1)
circuit.ry(parameter, 0)
circuit.measure_all()
print(circuit)

I would like to display a slider to adjust the value of x and animate how the Ry(x) gate transforms the qubit on the Bloch Sphere. What is the most appropriate method in Qiskit 1.0 to accomplish this visualization? Additionally, could this approach be scaled to visualize a parameterized circuit with two or three qubits?

Qiskit did have a feature that allows you to visualize rotations in the bloch sphere, but it has now been deprecated. It is still available in Qiskit 1.2 but it will be removed soon, so in a few months you might need to implement the feature yourself or use an older version of qiskit.
Here's an example:
from math import pi
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.visualization import visualize_transition

angle = pi/2

qc = QuantumCircuit(1)
qc.rx(angle,0)
visualize_transition(qc) 

Just change the value of angle or the type of rotation gate if you need to visualize something different. If you circuit is parametrized with a variable of type Parameter, then you need to assign some value to it for the visualization to work.
As for if this can be generalized for more than 1 qubit, the answer is no. The Bloch sphere can only be used to accurately visualize separable states, but in the case of 2 or more states they could be entangled so all you can see in the Bloch ball would be the Bloch vector of the reduced density matrix of each qubit, which is not unique for a given pure entangled state.
